# Android: open drawer by swipe

Tags: android, notification

There is a phone with Android 5.1.1.

I want to open the notification drawer by swiping down on the home screen.
I'm using [Car Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autolauncher.motorcar.free), it does not have this feature.

[image: image of notification drawer]

Can you recommend me an application which can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a different launcher, or an app to work with Car Launcher?  I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: The latter, yes. I like the car launcher but unfortunately it doesnt provide this feature by its own.